# Retornar um endereço usando Google Maps API

Tags: java, android, google-maps

Estou finalzando um aplicativo onde preciso utilizar o `Google Maps API` para duas coisas: selecionar um endereço a partir da escolha do usuário (exemplo: usuário navega até o endereço desejado e o escolhe) e mostrar o mapa com base na localização de um exemplo pré-definido (exemplo: abrir o mapa no endereço que o usuário escolheu anteriormente).

Li que é possível receber o endereço selecionado utilizando o seguinte código:

```
private GoogleMap mMap;

{...}

mMap.setOnMapClickListener(new OnMapClickListener() {

    @Override
    public void onMapClick(LatLng newLatLon) {
        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), point.toString(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();                       
    }
});
```

Porém eu gostaria de passar essa função para um botão externo ao mapa. Como posso fazer isso? E, embora eu tenha procurado como faço para abrir um mapa utilizando um endereço pré-definido, não consegui encontrar nada consiso. É possível passar um parâmetro do tipo `String` para a API?

Comment: Você gostaria de pegar a posição centrada no mapa ao clicar num botão e não dentro do Mapa (Existe o método `getCameraPosition`)? Para abrir o mapa numa posição pré-selecionada é preciso usar o método `moveCamera` (Configurando uma atualização de camera `CameraUpdate`) ou usar o método `animateCamera` (mesma coisa do moveCamera, porém é animado). Ambas as soluções usando a instância do `GoogleMap`.

Comment: Não sei se a posição centrada seria o mais correto para o que eu quero. Quero pegar o nome do endereço de uma rua que foi tocada pelo usuário e não suas coordenadas. Consigo fazer isso com o `getCameraPosition`? Vou pesquisar com relação ao `moveCamera`, obrigado pela dica.

Comment: Entendi o problema, você terá que usar a API do `GeoCoder`, que faz o reverso da localização e te fornece uma String com o endereço aproximado da posição. De uma olhada em http://developer.android.com/training/location/display-address.html.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Você vai ter que usar um reverse geolocation. Fiz um post sobre isso em 2010 ([Android: Reverse Geolocation](http://netomarin.com.br/blog/20101201/android-reverse-geolocation/)), mas o código pra essa parte não mudou muito.

A classe que contém os dados o endereço é a [Address](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/location/Address.html). Para saber cada campo e o que você pode obter do endereço, sugiro que visite a [documentação](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/location/Address.html). Abaixo o código de uma função que busca a cidade e a linha 1 de endereço, que para a maioria dos casos irá retornar o nome da rua. Mas tome cuidado que em alguns casos pode ser nula, por isso é bom fazer os testes adequados:

```
private void getCityByLocation(Location location) {
    //obtendo coordenadas
    double latPoint = location.getLatitude();
    double lngPoint = location.getLongitude();

    //Classe que fornece a localização da cidade
    Geocoder geocoder = new Geocoder(this.getApplicationContext());
    List myLocation = null;

    try {
        //Obtendo os dados do endereço
        myLocation = geocoder.getFromLocation(latPoint, lngPoint, 1);
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    if ( myLocation != null && myLocation.size() > 0) {
        Address a = myLocation.get(0);
        //Pronto! Vocêm tem o nome da cidade!
        String city = a.getLocality();
        String street = a.getAddressLine(0);
       //Seu código continua aqui...
    } else {
        Log.d("geolocation", "endereço não localizado");
    }
}
```

Comment: Muito obrigado, era isso mesmo que eu precisava!